# What's the value of $p$ if the roots of the biquadratic equation $x^4-10x^2+p=0$ are in AP?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

What's the value of $p$ if the roots of the biquadratic equation $$x^4-10x^2+p=0$$ are in AP?

The given equation is quadratic in $x^2$, so it's discriminant is $D=25-p\ge0\iff p\le25$ and the roots are $\left(x^2\right)_{1,2}=5\pm\sqrt{25-p}$. For $x$ we have $$x=\pm\sqrt{5+\sqrt{25-p}}$$ and $$x=\pm\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}},\text{ when } 5\ge\sqrt{25-p}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $t^4-2xt^2+y^2=0$ has $4$ real solutions in an arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659574/determine-x-y-in-mathbbr-such-that-t4-2xt2y2-0-has-4-real-solutions)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If the roots are $\ a-3d, a-d, a+d, a+3d\ $ (any arithmetic progression can be written in this form), what values of $\ a\ $ and $\ d\ $ will reduce the polynomial
$$
(x-a+3d)(x-a+d)(x-a-d)(x-a-3d)
$$
to the form
$$
x^4-10x^2+p\ ?
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why are we assuming that the equation has 4 real roots, though?

Comment: You don't need to assume that all the roots are real. If you recover *all* sets roots that are in arithmetic progression, including the complex ones, you'll also have all sets of real roots that are in arithmetic progression. (I'm not assuming that $\ a\ $ and $\ d\ $ are real.

Comment: May I ask you why did you decide to write the AP exactly as $a-3d, a-d, a+d, a+3d$?

Comment: I had initially taken the roots to be $\ a,$$\,a+d,$$\,a+2d,$$\,a+3d\ $. But when I wrote down the product $\ (x-a)$$(x-a-d)$$(x-a-2d)$$(x-a-3d)\ $, I noticed that if I doubled the difference and shifted $\ a\ $ down by $\ 3d\ $ I'd be able to simplify the calculation by pairing up the factors $\ x-a-d\ $ and $\ x-a+d\ $ and $\ x-a-3d\ $ and $\ x-a+3d\ $

Answer (score 0):

Based on symmetry, we can write the four roots as $a\pm b$, and $a\pm 3b$, where the common difference is equal to $d=2b$.  Then we have
\begin{align}
(x-(a+3b))(x-(a+b))(x-(a-b))(x-(a-3b))&=0\\
(x^2-2ax+a^2-b^2)(x^2-2ax+a^2-9b^2)&=0\\
x^4-4ax^3+(6a^2-10b^2)x^2+(20ab^2-4a^3)x+(a^4-10a^2b^2+9b^4)&=0
\end{align}
It then follows that
$$\left\{\begin{align}
-4a&=0\\
6a^2-10b^2&=-10\\
a^4-10a^2b^2+9b^4&=p
\end{align}\right.$$

We can see trivially that $a=0$, $b=\pm1$, and subsequently, $p=9$.

Comment: Should it be $p=9$?

Comment: @AlainRemillard yes!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the four roots (and condition on $p$ for these to be real), you could put them in order
$$-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{25-p}}$$
$$-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}}$$
$$\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}}$$
$$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{25-p}}$$
Since they have to be in an arithmetic progression, the difference between two consecutive roots must always be the same. We are able to create an equation for $p$

The difference between the third and second root is
$$2\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}}$$
The difference between the fourth and third root is
$$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{25-p}}-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}}$$
These two differences must be the same
$$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{25-p}}-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}} = 2\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}}$$
Then solving for $p$
$$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{25-p}} = 3\sqrt{5-\sqrt{25-p}}$$
$$5+\sqrt{25-p} = 9\left(5-\sqrt{25-p}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{25-p} = 4$$
$$p = 9$$
Finally, try this in your polynomial to make sure it works.
$$x^4-10x+9=(x^2-9)(x^2-1) = (x-3)(x+3)(x-1)(x+1)$$